# Poisson Process: number of costumers in a store

Tags: probability, poisson-process

Question: Your friend owns a hardware store. On Saturdays, the store is open from noon
to 7:00 p.m. During these hours, customers arrive according to a Poisson process at a rate
of λ customers per hour. One Saturday, after your friend closes his store, you ask him how
many customers he had that day. “Just one!” your friend replies. Without asking him when
the customer came, how is that customer’s arrival time distributed under the information
you now have?

I know that a Poisson process has a pmf given by: $P_X(k)=\frac{e^{-\mu}\mu^k}{k!}$. I find the wording of the question a bit confusing, so I'm not sure how to tackle this.

Answer (score 1):

Let the arrival time of the customer be $T$ hours after noon. Then $T$ will be uniformly distributed on the half-open interval $(0, 7]$. This follows from calculating the probability that $T \leq t$, given the information that $X = 1$, where $X$ is the number of customers in the given $7$ hour period.
$$P(T \leq t \mid X = 1) = \frac{P(T \leq t \cap X = 1)}{P(X = 1)}$$
The probability $P(T \leq t \cap X = 1)$ is the probability that $1$ customer comes in the first $t$ hours, and that no customers come in the next $7 - t$ hours. Using properties of the Poisson process,
$$P(T \leq t \mid X = 1) = \frac{e^{-\lambda t} (\lambda t) \cdot e^{-\lambda(7 - t)}}{7 \lambda e^{-7 \lambda}}$$
$$= \frac{t}{7}.$$
This is independent of the value of the value of $\lambda$.